# How does this cause a tree conflict in SVN and how do I fix or avoid it?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I often get tree conflicts in SVN when I'm doing minor refactoring.  I'll rename a directory and BOOM, tree conflict.  Just now I tried deleting two empty, unused packages from my project.  SVN complained that my working copy was out of date when I tried to commit, so I updated it and tried to commit again.  All of a sudden I get a tree conflict and I have no clue why.

I'll attach a screenshot of my IDE.  Hopefully it shows why I'm confused.  How can empty 
directories be in conflict with anything?

[image: SVN tree conflict in IntelliJ IDEA.]

Edit: I had this happen again tonight.  Right after a successful commit I tried to delete two empty directories.  My SVN client complained my working copy was out of date, so I updated it and all of a sudden I have tree conflicts.  Part of my successful commit was moving files out of the directories that ended up being empty, so, as far as I understand, they should have been at the current revision already and shouldn't have needed an update.

Comment: If I remember correctly, svn will generate a text file describing the tree conflict (it is true at least for svn client version >= 1.6.x).  May you take a look inside the file and tell you what's conflict svn complaining?

Comment: @Adrian.  I'm using 1.6, but I can't find any special files.  Are they extra files with a special name or is it part of an existing SVN file.  I saved a broken checkout, but there are a lot of files to go through. Tortoise SVN knows there's a tree conflict, so there must be some info in there somewhere.  I'm starting to think it's a problem with IDEA rather than something I'm doing: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-55148

Answer (score 0):

Even the Empty directories will also contains the .svn files in hidden format. So, before deleting the Empty directories from a SVN Checked Main Directory, you should first delete the .SVN files from the Empty directories which will be displayed by enabling the Hidden files. After deleting the .SVN files the SVN will not check for the directories which you have deleted, because always it will check for the hidden .svn files inside every directory. Hope  will resolve your problem.

Comment: Manually removing the .svn directory will never be the correct answer to that.  You are not supposed to delete .svn manually.  Moreover, I believe it is the parent directory's meta-data tracking that empty directory.  That means, removing .svn in the empty directory is not going to help, instead, it is leaving you a 'corrupted' working copy